# UIView difficulty

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiview

I tried adding a view with a white color like transparent so I set this:

```
self.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f,1024.0f,768.0f)];
[self.backgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[self.backgroundView setAlpha:0.5];
[self.backgroundView setOpaque:NO];
[self.view addSubview:self.backgroundView];


slotButton.frame = CGRectMake(550, 350, 400, 100);
[backgroundView addSubview:slotButton];
 }
```

But when I add a button in my view the button became transparent. What I wanted is to add a button to a white transparent view without making the `UIButton` transparent too.

Comment: why dont you add your button to `self.view` ??

Comment: How you are creating your button?

Comment: Yes futureelite is right, if you make background view transparent then it wii affect your subviews as well.So better to go with clearColor;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In stead of making your View transparent, only set its background color to transparent

Like this:

```
self.backgoundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255 green:255 blue:255 alpha:0.5];
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting the alpha property of the background view < 1 causes the entire view and any subviews inside (including the button) to become transparent. If you want only the background of the view to be transparent, set the view's background color to clear color.

```
self.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.backgroundView.opaque = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is quite simple. You need to have two UIView. Set all the properties like transparency, background color or alpha on the second view and add it on first view. Now add your buttons on the first view. And you are done.

Cheers,

Tarun.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.5];
self.backgroundView.alpha = 1.0;
```